# How do i select columns based on multiple strings?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following column names:

```
Name1_a, 
Name1_b, 
Name1_c, 
Name2_a, 
Val1_a, 
Val1_b, 
Val2_a, 
Var1_a, 
Var1_b, 
temp1, 
temp2, 
temp3
```

How do I write an SQL query where I can select columns that start with Name, Val and Var?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without REGEXP?

Comment: Those are column names. @ErgestBasha

Comment: I am getting these column names similar to this after having to do a One-Hot Encoding.

Comment: Yes. It is irrespective of the records. Just that the columns have to be used for further tasks.

Comment: Don't spread an "array" across columns.